# How to pass Query to Ireport table control through jsp

Tags: jsp, jasper-reports

I am working on *iReport 5.5* and *MySQL 5.0*. I have created a jrxml file which has one table control. I have passed below query to it.

```
    select invoice_no,start_date,gross_amount from tbl_invoice where client="ABC Cars"
```

Now, i want to pass parameter to it through JSP page. Please solve my query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are planning to generate a report from your JSP application, you can follow this tutorial (it talks about JSF, but basically it's the same) : [JSF + JPA + JasperReports](http://www.ramkitech.com/2011/11/jsf-jpa-jasperreports-ireport.html). In the above case, on this line `jasperPrint=JasperFillManager.fillReport(reportPath, new HashMap(),beanCollectionDataSource);` it specifies a new empty HashMap. It is used to pass parameters to the report. On this link you can see that you can pass several elements to such a map, and use it to pass them as parameters to the report: [Passing parameters to JasperReports](http://kristantohans.wordpress.com/tag/tutorial-jasper-report/)